# Pyspark: Merge all zipped csvs into one csv in python

Tags: python, pyspark

If I have huge data in the form of zipped csvs, how can I combine it into a single csv file (zipped output or not doesn't matter)?

I am reading it into a spark Dataframes but then I am stuck on how to concatenate pyspark Dataframes.

Below is my code that runs a loop and wants to append Dataframe for each loop run:

```
        schema=StructType([])
        result = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
        for day in range(1,31):
            day_str = str(day) if day>=10 else "0"+str(day)
            print 'Ingesting %s' % day_str
            df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3a://key/201811%s" % (day_str))
            result = result.unionAll(df)

        result.write.save("s3a://key/my_result.csv", format='csv')
```

This gives me error `AnalysisException: u"Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 0 columns and the second table has 1 columns;;\n'Union\n:- LogicalRDD\n+- Relation[_c0#75] csv\n"`. Could anyone help me how can I proceed?

Comment: I don't know anything about pyspark, but the error message you mention suggests to me that you have to first conform each csv so that you're combining Dataframes with the same shapes.  Maybe you need to read each one and then change it to a common shape that you can get all Dataframes to so that they can be combined.

Comment: I would not use .option("inferSchema") against data on S3. Spark will read the entire file just to infer that schema. It not only doubles your execution time, it doubles your cost. Do it once, log the inferred schema, put it in your code for next time
Similarly: better to save to a format like Parquet or ORC for followon queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
result=spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema_mw)

for day in range(1,31):
    day_str = str(day) if day>=10 else "0"+str(day)
    print 'Ingesting %s' % day_str

    df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").option("delimiter", ",").schema(schema_mw).load("s3a://bucket/201811%s" % (day_str))

    if result:
        result = result.union(df)
    else:
        result = df
result.repartition(1).write.save("s3a://bucket/key-Compiled", format='csv', header=False)
```

This works, however, when I try to load header as true in the last step for repartitioning, the header is stored as a row. I am not sure how to add those headers as a header and not as a row though.